# Спряжение глагола лежать

Tags: глаголы

К какому спряжению относится глагол лежать? Он имеет ударные личные окончания, по которым определяется второе спряжение. Однако некоторые учителя относят его к глаголам первого спряжения по окончанию неопределенной формы. Почему возникли такие разногласия и все-таки к какому спряжению следует отнести данный глагол?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может, Вы не поняли учителя.

Дело в том,что по инфинитиву определяем спряжение глаголов только  с БЕЗУДАРНЫМИ личными окончаниями. А для тех глаголов, где окончание ударное, берём полную парадигму: если в ней присутствуют окончания -ишь, -ит, -ат(-ят), мы отнесем ко 2 спряжению, -ешь,-ем, -ете,-ют - к  1.

Рассмотрим глагол "лежАть".Спрягаем:

я леж-у мы леж-ИМ

ты леж-ИШЬ вы леж-ИТЕ

он леж-ИТ они леж-АТ

Парадигма 2 спряжения, не ошибёшься, поменять на первое не получится, под ударением произносится только так, не лежЕт, лежУт.

И еще надо помнить о разноспрягаемых глаголах БЕЖАТЬ, ХОТЕТЬ и др.,которые имеют личные окончания и 1, и 2 спряжения.

я бегу, мы бежим

ты бежишь вы бежите

он бежит они БЕГУТ (форма 1 спряжения).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я сама учитель, но не учитель русского языка. Я прочитала именно такое объяснение, как Вы дали мне. Но ученица одного из лицеев в нашем городе настаивала на том, что их учитель русского языка настаивает на том, что по окончанию глагола это глагол первого спряжения. Потом обратилась к Интернету, и там тоже нашла информацию о том, что некоторые учителя говорят, что это глагол первого спряжения.

Comment: Знаете, учителя тоже разные, я одно время в гороно работала, пришла на открытый урок претендентки на звание, а она правильный ответ ученика на неправильное исправляет и гонит какую-то пургу, что это спорно. Не слушайте, других правил нет, спряжение определяют по парадигме - окончаниям  глагола, а оно под ударением - не ошибёшься, а вот в безударных окончаниях как раз по спряжению пишут окончания.